# Java generics and "..."

Tags: java, java-5

1. What do `T` and `S` mean?
2. `public void main(String... abc)` ;   what does `...` mean? Is `...` called generic as well?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

1. That are [parameterized types](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.5/pdf/generics-tutorial.pdf). You can use any identifier here to represent a certain object type.
2. That are [varargs](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.5.0/docs/guide/language/varargs.html). You can pass a single String, or multiple Strings, or a String array in.

Answer (score 3):

`T` and `S` are generic classes.  They can be any type of class that you want.  For example, `Map<K, V>` uses the `K` for the key class and `V` for the value class.

```
Map<Integer, String> map = new HashMap<Integer, String>
```

As for the `String...`, it means any number of String parameters.

Comment: 1.can i use any other alphabet , A,B,C,Z ? rather than T,S,K,V ?
2. is Map(K,V) same as Map(S,T) ? can use any alphabet?

Comment: You can use any identifier you want as long as it does't clash with existing classnames in the classpath. The normal coding convention is indeed a single uppercased character (because it is not normal to have a class with only one character as name).

Answer (score 1):

1. Please read [the documentation](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.5.0/docs/guide/language/generics.html). Briefly, they are type parameters so that generic types and methods can know what type of objects they are acting on.
2. That indicates that the method can accept a variable number of arguments. See [varargs](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.5.0/docs/guide/language/varargs.html). It's basically sugar around an array.

Answer (score 1):

Sun's Java Generics documentation can be a bit hard to understand at times, so I tried to write a simpler tutorial on Java Generics. You can find it here:

http://tutorials.jenkov.com/java-generics/index.html

Answer (score 0):

complementing: 
 `String...` is almost the same as `String[]`.
On the method side it is the same,
on the calling side the're is a difference: the compiler creates the array from the parameters.

```
void method(String... args) {
    // args is an array: getClass() returns [java.lang.String
    if (args.length >  0) {
        System.out.println(args[0]);
...
    method();               // same as method(new String[0]);
    method("1", "2", "3");  // same as method(new String[] {"1", "2", "3"});
```

Answer (score 0):

T and S means that the class itself does not know what classes they are, but things that use the class do.

Take java.util.List. The list class does not know anything about T and makes no assumptions about T. Things that **use** the List class:

```
List<MyBean> l = new ArrayList<MyBean>();
```

Know what's in it.